# Thread safety with decorator pattern

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, design-patterns

This is rather long but I will try to be as clear as I can.

I have an interface, lets call it `IFoo`

```cpp
class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual void reset(const Bar* bar) = 0;
    virtual int calculate(int i) const = 0;
};
```

a basic implementation

```cpp
class FooBasic : public IFoo
{
private:
    int _value;
public:
    FooBasic(int value) : _value(value) {}

    virtual void reset(const Bar* bar) override {}
    virtual int calculate(int i) const override { return _value; }
};
```

and I have a base decorator for the interface

```cpp
class FooDecorator : public IFoo
{
protected:
    IFoo* _foo;
public:
    FooDecorator(IFoo* foo) : _foo(foo) {}

    virtual void reset(const Bar* bar) override { _foo->reset(bar); }
    virtual int calculate(int i) const override { return _foo->calculate(i); }
};
```

and I have a tonne of implementations of the decorator which take pretty much the same form

```cpp
class FooInt : public FooDecorator
{
private:
    int _y;
    int _z;
public:
    FooInt(IFoo* foo) : FooDecorator(foo), _y(0), _z(0) {}

    virtual void reset(const Bar* bar) override
    {
        _foo->reset(bar);
        _y = bar->expensiveIntFunction(15);
        _z = bar->expensiveIntFunction(10);
    }
    virtual int calculate(int i) const override { return _y*_foo->calculate(i) + _z; }
};

class FooIntStar : public FooDecorator
{
private:
    const int* _z;
public:
    FooIntStar(IFoo* foo) : FooDecorator(foo), _z(nullptr) {}

    virtual void reset(const Bar* bar) override
    {
        _foo->reset(bar);
        _z = bar->expensiveIntStarFunction();
    }
    virtual int calculate(int i) const override { return _foo->calculate(i)*_z[i]; }
};
```

The idea here is that clients of the `IFoo` interface will first call the `reset()` method passing in their `Bar` object. Then they will call the `calculate()` method millions of times with different integer parameters. The `IFoo` implementations will on the call to `reset()` extract some information from the `Bar` object and use it to set some internal members which they will then use to decorate the result from the underlying `IFoo` object. What they extract from the bar object depends on the implementation and could be different types/values.

This all works OK as long as there is a single client using the `IFoo` implementation. I am now trying to introduce some threading where I have different clients using the `IFoo` implementations concurrently. Each client has its own `Bar` object but I would like them to use the same instances of the `IFoo` objects (if possible). In the current state this will not work because the call to `reset()` sets member variables i.e. the `reset()` method is not `const`.

My plan it to create a workspace object which then gets passed around. Each client will own its own instance of the workspace to avoid conflict when several clients use the same object. On the call to reset, the `IFoo` implementations will set the temporary data in the workspace and not use internal members. However, since the type of data required for the different implementations is different it is tricky designing this workspace in advance.

One idea I have come up with is to make this workspace abstract and have the implementations extend it. So I'm thinking of changing the interface to

```cpp
// Totally undefined object
struct IFooWorkspace
{
    virtual ~IFooWorkspace(){}
};

class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual IFooWorkspace* createWorkspace() const = 0;
    virtual void reset(IFooWorkspace* workspace, const Bar* bar) const = 0;
    virtual int calculate(IFooWorkspace* workspace, int i) const = 0;
};
```

and for instance the `FooInt` implementation

```cpp
class FooInt : public FooDecorator
{
private:
    // Struct definition instead of member variables
    struct WorkSpace : IFooWorkspace
    {
        WorkSpace() : _y(0), _z(0), _ws(nullptr) {}
        virtual ~WorkSpace(){ delete _ws; }
        int _y;
        int _z;
        IFooWorkspace* _ws;
    };
public:
    FooInt(IFoo* foo) : FooDecorator(foo) {}

    virtual IFooWorkspace* createWorkspace() const override
    {
        WorkSpace* ws = new WorkSpace;
        ws->_ws = _foo->createWorkspace();
        return ws;
    }

    virtual void reset(IFooWorkspace* workspace, const Bar* bar) const override
    {
        WorkSpace& ws = dynamic_cast<WorkSpace&>(*workspace);
        ws._y = bar->expensiveIntFunction(15);
        ws._z = bar->expensiveIntFunction(10);
        _foo->reset(ws._ws, bar);
    }

    virtual int calculate(IFooWorkspace* workspace, int i) const override
    {
        const WorkSpace& ws = dynamic_cast<WorkSpace&>(*workspace);
        return ws._y*_foo->calculate(ws._ws, i) + ws._z;
    }
};
```

So the new plan is that clients will call `createWorkspace()` first and own the `IFooWorkspace` object returned. Then subsequent calls to `reset()` and `calculate()` should pass this workspace.

My problem is that it all looks rather convoluted and I'm not sure about the `dynamic_cast` in terms of safety and performance. So the question is: is there a simpler, cleaner way to achieve thread safety here? Ideally I would like to avoid creating new instances for the IFoo objects.

Comment: And what's the problem with creating instances of IFoo derivatives in thread specific storage? Like all threads will have unique set of them.

Comment: I presume the `_y(0), _z(0)` initializations in the second `FooInt` incarnation are unintended.

Comment: Why cannot you just use critical sections in order to synchronise your threads?

Comment: @c-smile: The way the `IFoo`s are created is rather convoluted and that's why I'm trying to avoid creating new instances. But maybe I just need to dig in and do it.
@MattPhillips: The initialisations were a copy and paste error. I have edited the post.
@HenriqueBarcelos: I think with the way things are, critical sections will kill performance - we might as well not bother with threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ideally I would like to avoid creating new instances for the IFoo objects.

But you've no problem creating new instances of workspaces, so I can assume that it is the constructing of foo objects that is painful in someway.

I think that a factory pattern would suit.

```
class IFooFactory
{
public:
    virtual IFoo create(const Bar* bar) = 0;
};

class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual int calculate(int i) const = 0;
};
```

`Foo`'s then become like your `Workspace` objects, even if they are complex to create, a factory encapsulates that job. The `reset` has become the `create` method.

The factories can be safely shared among threads as they have no mutable state.

Example factory:

```
class FooIntFactory : public IFooFactory
{
public:
    virtual IFoo create(const Bar* bar) const override
    {
        return new FooInt(bar);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the different data types you need to plan for are relatively inter-substitutable (e.g. `int` vs `double`) then you could try templatizing `IFoo`.

As it is, introducing a `IFooWorkspace` only makes sense if there is a lot of shared state between subclasses--i.e. if the actual implementation of `IFooWorkspace` has something in it.  Otherwise why bother?  You have achieved no decoupling between `Workspace` and `FooInt`--the former would be built only for the latter, and the latter can accomplish nothing without the former.  You might as well just make `_y`, `_z` part of `FooInt`.  But if there is a meaningful hierarchy of workspace subclasses then I think your design is okay, except for the question of where these workspaces are going to get called, but I suppose the calling code will handle that.